# Using $scope variable inside AngularJS script

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using AngularJS, [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/) and Cordova. I tried to set current user location in the center of the map.

Here is my code:

```
.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.position = "";
    var latLng = {};
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
          $scope.position = position;
          latLng = {
            'lat': position.coords.latitude,
            'lng': position.coords.longitude
          };
        });
      });
    };
    $scope.map = {
      center: {
        latitude: 51.219053,
        longitude: 4.404418
      },
      ...
```

I can print current user location this way outside the script:

```
clat: {{position.coords.latitude}}, clang: {{position.coords.longitude}}
```

But I want to use it inside the script. I have tried these without any success:

```
center: { latitude: position.coords.latitude,...
center: { latitude: $scope.position.coords.latitude,...
center: { latitude: latLng.lng,...
center: { latitude: latLng['lng'],...
```

How can use it inside the script?

---

**Error log:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined
```

Comment: check you console for error

Comment: That's because geolocation is asynchronous

Comment: Is the `$apply` necessary when the function call takes place within a controller?

Comment: It is necessary as it's called from 3rd party function (i.e. native browser methods)

Comment: @marcospereira why you broke the formatting?

Comment: It is not really clear what you are trying to accomplish here.  What does "inside the script" and "outside the script" mean?

Comment: in the code, I want put position.coords.latitude instead 51.219053 when googlemap loads.

Comment: @maurycy sorry. Its ok now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to initialise googleMaps after getting the coords you can do it nicelly with promises

[working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/x20xHvMlXDrfmct0U1T3)

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $q) {
  var deferredBrowserLocation = $q.defer()

  getBrowserLocation = function() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      console.log(position.coords)
      deferredBrowserLocation.resolve(position)

    })
    return deferredBrowserLocation.promise
  }

  getBrowserLocation().then(function(position) {
    $scope.map = {
      center: {
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude
      }
    }
  }).finally(function(){
    //initialize googlemaps with $scope.map
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is because you are trying to access coords before it has been set, this happens asynchronously.

It may be that it works elsewhere in the code simply because there is a delay before that code is run, which is enough time for the coordinates to have been set. This is known as a race condition.

You set the values from coords in a callback function as below.

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){

     //Check coords is not undefined and then build the center object
}
```

}